Merging/joining spreadsheet columns in python that have a different number of rows
Prefacing this with the fact I am a biologist and know nothing of coding or python.
I am trying to combine two excel sheets that have a different number of rows, one column that "matches" i.e other than lacking the same number of rows has the same numbers in it and a second column that almost matches (there are only 22 exact matches in around 4000 rows) and I need them to combine.
First Spreadsheet
Second Spreadsheet
I NEED a spreadsheet that contains the SR, MP, VH, and SL columns matched on SR and MP.
I was expecting to get a spreadsheet that contains the SR, MP, VH, and SL columns that matched/joined on SR and MP.
I tried a fuzzy join and fuzzy merge since the MP column is off by a few decimals but ran into the issue of having a different number of rows in each spreadsheet.
